# GPUImage show histogram in another view

Tags: ios, objective-c, histogram, gpuimage, gpuimagestillcamera

I am currently trying to display a histogram using GPUImage.  I currently have following code:

```
GPUImageOutput<GPUImageInput> *filter = [[GPUImageHistogramFilter alloc] initWithHistogramType:kGPUImageHistogramLuminance];
[self.stillCamera  removeTarget:filter];
GPUImageGammaFilter *gammaFilter = [[GPUImageGammaFilter alloc] init];
[self.stillCamera  addTarget:gammaFilter];
[gammaFilter addTarget:filter];

GPUImageHistogramGenerator *histogramGraph = [[GPUImageHistogramGenerator alloc] init];

[histogramGraph forceProcessingAtSize:CGSizeMake(500.0, 500)];
[filter addTarget:histogramGraph];

GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter *blendFilter = [[GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter alloc] init];
blendFilter.mix = 0.75;
[blendFilter forceProcessingAtSize:CGSizeMake(500, 500)];

[self.stillCamera addTarget:blendFilter];
[histogramGraph addTarget:blendFilter];

[blendFilter addTarget:previewView];
```

Above shows the histogram overplayed over my previewView.  (It does flicker however, another issue, another day)

I want to show this histogram on a smaller view in a particular location on the view.  How can I do this?

Comment: I think a `GPUImageTransformFilter` with a translation transform would be a good place to start.

Comment: I cannot be the only person wanting to display this graph on a separate view right? I would imagine there's a formal way to pump this out to another view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show histogram in separate view you need add another `GPUImageView` to your main view and point histogram filter to it. Here is source code based on `SimpleImageFilter` sample.

```
- (void)loadView
{    
    CGRect mainScreenFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

    GPUImageView *primaryView = [[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:mainScreenFrame];
    self.view = primaryView;

    UIImage *inputImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"WID-small.jpg"];
    GPUImagePicture *sourcePicture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:inputImage smoothlyScaleOutput:YES];

    // Creating another view to show histogram
    GPUImageView *histView = [[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(mainScreenFrame.size.width - 100, mainScreenFrame.size.height - 100, 100, 100)];
    [primaryView addSubview:histView];

    // Create histogram filter and generator and point it to histogram view
    GPUImageOutput<GPUImageInput> *histFilter = [[GPUImageHistogramFilter alloc] initWithHistogramType:kGPUImageHistogramLuminance];
    GPUImageOutput<GPUImageInput> *histGenerator = [[GPUImageHistogramGenerator alloc] init];
    [histGenerator forceProcessingAtSize:histView.sizeInPixels];
    [sourcePicture addTarget:histFilter];
    [histFilter addTarget:histGenerator];
    // Note target - hist view
    [histGenerator addTarget:histView];

    // Setup sepia filter just to show main picture
    GPUImageOutput<GPUImageInput> *sepiaFilter = [[GPUImageSepiaFilter alloc] init];
    [sepiaFilter forceProcessingAtSize:primaryView.sizeInPixels];
    [sourcePicture addTarget:sepiaFilter];
    // Note target - main view
    [sepiaFilter addTarget:primaryView];

    [sourcePicture processImage];
}
```

And final result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you! I successfully got it to show up.  Now, with your method, How do I extract just the luminance or RGB only histograms?

Comment: I am seeing the main preview window is dropping frames considerably when I use this method.  Any ideas on how to improve this? Separate queue?